# Calling Google Sheets API in Swift with GTMAppAuth

Tags: swift, macos, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to read/write to Google Sheets in Swift on macOS.
I'm using the **[GAppAuth](https://github.com/elsesiy/GAppAuth)** library which in turn makes use of **[GTMAppAuth](https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth)**.

I managed to get authorized and get back both the access token and the refresh token but I still get an HTTP status code of 403 when I try to make a call to one of the Google Sheets' endpoints.

In `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)` I appended the following authorization scope, as detailed in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get?apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%221_yl7lk0Fq0zl42mamrYE1GTRznmHYl_h5cWmIFsuYOc%22%7D):

```
GAppAuth.shared.appendAuthorizationRealm("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly")
```

But still, I get 403. What am I doing wrong? Am I adding the scope properly?

This is the code where I make the API call:

```
@IBAction func getSpreadsheet(_ sender: NSButton) {
    
    let fetcherService = GTMSessionFetcherService()
    fetcherService.authorizer = authorization
    let spreadsheetInfo = URL(string: "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetID}")
    let fetcher = GTMSessionFetcher(url: spreadsheetInfoEndpoint)
    fetcher.beginFetch { (data, error) in
        //Error code 403
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there @nasonov! I see that you are using the third-party [GAppAuth](https://github.com/elsesiy/GAppAuth) library instead of the official [Google Auth](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-swift) repository. To better determine where the issue originates, could you please request a valid token using Google Auth and use it on the Sheets API request?

Comment: Thanks Jacques, I'll definitely check it out.
When looking at the [doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) I stopped at the resources linked at the bottom. It didn't come to my mind there would be others in the Google APIs repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by looking at the cURL request with the Google API Explorer. The access token parameter was missing:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[SPREADSHEETID]/values/[RANGE]?access_token=[access_token]
```

Also thanks to Jacques-Guzel Heron, in the comment section, who let me know of the official [Google Auth Library for Swift](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-swift). I'll check it out.